# How to convert a date in a textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.publicHoliday.Date)`  I want to display the Date as `dd MMM yyyy` and not using data Annotations...

I am also having the Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#publicHoliday_Date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' , altField:'dd-M-yy', altFormat:'d/m/y' });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with:

```
@Html.TextBox("publicHoliday.Date", String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Model.publicHoliday.Date))
```

... or you could use this in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.publicHoliday.Date)
```

and create a folder named `EditorTemplates` inside your `[AppRoot]/Views/Shared` folder, where you put a partial view named `DateTime.cshtml` with the following content:

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBox("publicHoliday.Date", String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Model))
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#publicHoliday_Date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', altField: 'dd-M-yy', altFormat: 'd/m/y' });
    });
</script>
```

Not the most flexible solution, but it should work!